# Filter Logstash Sonicwall

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elk, sonicwall

I'm using ELK and I wanted to know where I can insert filters to analyze Sonicwall logs and view them in the grafana.

Would you put it in the filter.conf of the logstash?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Comment: I would suggest you to add some sample log lines to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic might add a module for `Sonicwall` in future filebeat release. Checkout [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-module-sonicwall.html). It is part of x-pack license but you can try it out in the trial version.

Alternatively, you can use a combination of filebeat & logstash to scrape and parse the logs and ingest it in Elastic Search. Grafana can connect to Elasticsearch directly so you can use it to create visualisations and dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

Log settings, then Log Analyze. The logs can be exported to csv, txt, filtered.  They are there, just look in the lower left.